# swig D bindings using extern(C) clashes with existing extern(C) functions

Tags: c, d, swig, extern

Currently Swig D bindings uses the following for a symbol `libfun`:

```
mixin(bindCode("libfun", "D_libfun"));
extern(C) int function(void* jarg1) libfun;
```

where `D_libfun` symbol is defined in a cxx wrapper compiled as a library. Thus, the symbol `libfun` is exported as `extern(C)` and has global scope. I faced cases where the symbols clashed with existing `extern(C)` symbols (eg read), resulting in obscure runtime crashes that I traced back to this swig file.

Is there a way to:

- avoid introducing extern(C) intermediate declarations
- or, add a user-specified prefix or suffix to those symbols (eg: `extern(C) mylib_libfun`), and reflecting this in both the main and auxiliary wrapper d files.

Right now I need to run a cumbersome postprocessor on those files and this is fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Your second suggested solution is the easiest solution. You can do this using [SWIG's advanced renaming](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) to do it all in one go.

For example given the function:

```
void read();
```

We can wrap it, with an automatically inserted prefix of `mylib_` by doing:

```
%module test

%rename("mylib_%s") "";

void read();
```

Comment: Let me clarify: I want to change only the extern(C) intermediate function defined in mylib_im.d (which will introduce name clashes), not the exposed interface function defined in mylib.d, whose name should be the same as in the original library; that one is not extern(C) so there is no name clashes possible. That's essentially the solution I've taken but I was hoping SWIG would provide this out of the box as others will face the same issue.

Comment: @user1426932 - I don't think there's currently a better solution than what I showed there combined with sed. (It's less fragile to remove things - you can write an expression that only keeps `mylib_` if it's preceded by `modulename.` for example). I patched the SWIG trunk locally to insert a prefix for non-members. [Patch #1](http://people.debian.org/~awoodland/0001-added-extra-prefix-to-proxy-code-too.patch) [Patch #2](http://people.debian.org/~awoodland/0002-Only-insert-mangling-for-free-functions.patch). It seems to work for me, feel free to forward it upstream if you think it's useful.